# My scale and rotate animation not performing as intended (CGAffineTransformConcat)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

I want to perform scale and rotate animation simultaneously but instead only scale animation is performed over time as intended, while rotation takes place instantly.

this is the code I use:

```
    CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationRatio);

CGAffineTransform entireAnimation = CGAffineTransformConcat(scale, rotate);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^(void){

                     view.transform = entireAnimation;

                 }completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];
```

even if I change concat order like this, issue remains the same:

```
CGAffineTransform entireAnimation = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotate,scale);
```

And the issue is: Instead of both scaling and rotating at the same time, my view is instantly rotated and scaling animation is performed over time.

How can I achieve simultaneous transformation animation ?

**EDIT: Rotation doesn't work if rotation ratio is 2*M_PI. Why doesn't the 360 degrees rotation work and how to make it work?**

Comment: I’ve tested you code and it’s working fine (just replaced yours `rotationRatio` for example with `M_PI/3`, scaleRatio, etc…